# VS Code Debug console escaping line breaks, support for ipython?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, escaping, ipython, vscode-debugger

UPDATE: I found out my actual issue is that VSCode does not use ipthon (as far as I can tell) in the debugging console (I am used to sypder).   VSCode says it supports Jupiter notebooks but I cannot find any reference to how to use ipthon when debugging although there is an an old comment on stackoverfow saying its coming in a future version but the link is dead.   So for now its back to spyder.  I left the original question for those newbies to VSCode who are stumped by the same issue.

Sorry for the very simple question but I just started using VS Code and when debugging python scripts the output in the debug console escapes line breaks.  How do I stop that behavior?

For example :

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10),columns=['Close'])

If I enter df into the debug console I get:

df

```
Close\n0       0\n1       1\n2       2\n3       3\n4       4\n5       5\n6       6\n7       7\n8       8\n9       9
```

Comment: Forgot to mention the json configuration is for version 0.2.0 Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Check if [VSCode 1.43 (Feb. 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/1cfe562df28b8e9ca9e9786ee2650242c69f277c/release-notes/v1_43.md#vs-code-debug-no-longer-escaping-whitespace) will help:

> ### VS Code Debug no longer escaping whitespace
>
> The VS Code debugger UI no longer escapes or quotes any whitespace received from a debug extension or debug adapter.
>   For example all strings received in DAP Variables or as DAP Output events are shown in the UI as they are without modification.
>
> This means that it is now up to the debug extension or debug adapter to decide if whitespace needs to be escaped before sending the data to VS Code.
>   More details can be found in [#73845](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73845) and [commit f647e12](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/f647e122015f17594f0a2d63fa151d6b1c84403d).